# How to remove catfish from pond

Tags: fish

We have catfish and blue gill in our pond. Is there a way to remove only the catfish? We are afraid the the catfish will eat the blue gill. Having catfish specific bait could work too (if that exists).

Comment: How large is the pond? And are there any other fish in there except those two?

Comment: Is the provide the cat fish with sufficient food (algae wafers for instance), it shouldn't feel included to eat other fish.

Comment: @Philipp the pond is 1/3 acre and there are only bluefish and catfish

Comment: @spikey_richie we don't have algae in the pond since there is a vegetative barrier that keeps the fertilizer out of the pond.

Comment: Selective fishing? use a net, only return the bluegill

Comment: If it is a 1/3 acre pond other fish may end up in there anyway, I would say start fishing for the catfish! Birds can spread fish eggs believe it or not by pooping them out and they can still hatch.

Comment: @nak5120 I meant adding an algae wafer feed for the catfish.